# Lane detection with Open cv and Python: how to improve HoughLines detection?

Tags: python, opencv

I have to perform a lane detection with Python  and OpenCV.
My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math

image=cv2.imread('road.jpg')
gray=cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,200)
while True:
   lines= cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, math.pi/180.0, 100, np.array([]), 0, 0)
   a,b,c = lines.shape
   for i in range(a):
        rho = lines[i][0][0]
        theta = lines[i][0][1]
        a = math.cos(theta)
        b = math.sin(theta)
        x0, y0 = a*rho, b*rho
        pt1 = ( int(x0+1000*(-b)), int(y0+1000*(a)) )
        pt2 = ( int(x0-1000*(-b)), int(y0-1000*(a)) )
        cv2.line(image, pt1, pt2, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow(" road ",image)
if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
    break
```

These are input and output:

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

I need to improve the houghlines detection to find only the lines that correspond to the lane. How can I do it?

Comment: You could threshold your input image in a way to keep only the probable color of the lane (yellow and white) I think. You can also use the HSV colorspace for that.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now I have another question. How do you think I can measure the distance from the camera to the lines i have previously found?

Comment: The title would be more related to "how to filter" rather than "how to improve" hough lines. For the second question, is very unclear what you are asking. Distance from camera to lines... they go to the skyline :S

Comment: The original problem I have to solve is to program a robot to go forward staying between two black lines. I was able to detect the lines but, to keep the robot between them, I have to know the distance between camera and each line.

Comment: Anyone that can help me?